# How can I efficiently calculate the number of actions a user has made in a month?

Tags: mysql

I have a database with two tables: one table which lists several users, and another table which lists every action those users made, the id of the user who made the action, and the date of the action.

I'm trying to calculate the number of actions each user has made each month. I'm not sure how to efficiently do this: does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`MONTH()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) to extract the month from the `DATE` and then `GROUP BY` both `MONTH` and `USER_ID`:

```
SELECT u.user_id, MONTH(a.date), COUNT(*) number_of_actions
FROM users u INNER JOIN actions a ON (u.user_id = a.user_id)
GROUP BY u.user_id, MONTH(a.date)
```

Also, if the user actions span multiple years, and you want to have different counts for *January 2011* and *January 2012*,  group by *both* `YEAR` and `MONTH` instead:

```
SELECT u.user_id, YEAR(a.date), MONTH(a.date), COUNT(*) number_of_actions
FROM users u INNER JOIN actions a ON (u.user_id = a.user_id)
GROUP BY u.user_id, YEAR(a.date), MONTH(a.date)
```

Comment: Will that query be inefficient if I have a lot of users or actions? Thanks for answering :)

Comment: @Christofian: It depends. How many users and actions are we talking about? There are ways to optimize it, not the query itself, but your database. For example, to add an index to the `user_id` field in the `actions` table. This will optimize the join between the two tables. To optimize the `GROUP BY`, you could use a function index on `MONTH(date)`, but I think MySQL doesn't support those. An alternative, is to denormalize the `actions` table and add a `MONTH` column to it, that you can index.

Answer (score 0):

If @Joao Silva's answer is too slow, you can maintain counts as actions happen in a separate table in a separate table using a trigger or stored procedure for updates.  If a disk based table is too slow, you could use a memory table and rebuild it if the server restarts, or use a Redis instance to keep this information.